# How can I in migration to set index name automatically manually?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-migrations

In laravel 9 app running migration with statement(mysql database) :

```
$table->foreignId('notification_config_id')
 ->nullable()
 ->references('id')
 ->on('notification_configs')
 ->onUpdate('RESTRICT')
 ->onDelete('RESTRICT');
```

I got error :

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1059 Identifier name 'notification_configs_notification_types_notification_config_id_foreign' is too long (SQL: alter table `notification_configs_notification_types` add constraint `notification_configs_notification_types_notification_config_id_foreign` foreign key (`notification_config_id`) references `notification_configs` (`id`) on delete RESTRICT on update RESTRICT)

looks like name of the index is set automatically, can I set it manually ?
I tried :

```
$table->foreignId('notification_config_id')
 ->nullable()->references('id')
 ->on('notification_configs')
 ->onUpdate('RESTRICT')
 ->onDelete('RESTRICT')
 ->name('notification_configs_longname_ref');
```

But the same error anyway...
How that can be fixed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `$table->foreignId()` you can use `$table->foreign()`. Method **foreign()** accepts a second paramater as name of the key.
So your migration code could include something like this :

```
$table->foreign('notification_config_id', 'notification_config_foreign_id')->nullable()->references('id')->on('notification_configs')->onUpdate('RESTRICT')->onDelete('RESTRICT');
```